# Single word denoting transition of something from present to future time

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word in dictionary, which denotes transition from present to future.

Use case: I have a powerpoint slide which contains two graphs in same slide. One graph shows company's present revenue and other graph shows projected revenue after 2 years. I am looking for a word which can help making the title of such slide. Which will denote transition from present to future

Comment: "Projected revenue change/transition/variation/shift over two years." This is straight to the point and not stuffy (depending on which word you choose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existence of just two data points seems insufficient justification for a title that suggests a *transition* rather than a simple *change*, because there are no intermediate data points that would be capable of demonstrating a trend.

But there are alternative solutions, such as

> *Comparison of present revenue with projected revenue after two years,*

---

> *Current revenue versus projected revenue after two years,*

---

> *Current revenue versus projected revenue two years hence,*

or better still, Jonathan Spirit's excellent suggestion,

> *Projected revenue change over two years*.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to be presenting is a ***forecast*** of future revenue.

> 1a :  to calculate or predict (some future event or condition) usually as a result of study and analysis of available pertinent data; *especially* :  to predict (weather conditions) on the basis of correlated meteorological observations
>   1b :  to indicate as likely to occur
>   <sub>(Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forecast))</sub>

Comment: Alternatively: extrapolation, ["to project, extend, or expand (known data or experience) into an area not known or experienced so as to arrive at a usually conjectural knowledge of the unknown area" (M-W)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extrapolate)

Answer (score 1):

after your data is presented call it "Fortified" then when you put your slide up call it a "fortified aspirational goal". In for a penny in for the pound;)

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that the focus of your slide is the change ( possibly in positive terms) of the company revenues:

I'd simply use as a possible title:

> - Future (2015/2016)  projection and development of company revenues!